# Unity3D C# Physics.OverlapSphere doesn't sort layers even if I define a sorting layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an enemy that checks if the player is around him with OverlapSphere. Although I defined a sorting layer (playerMask) it includes all the other layers, so the code always works even when the player is not around.

```
if(Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, alertRange, playerMask) != null) {
// do something
}
```

[The player object is in the "Player" layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/256yr.png). and [The layer mask is set in the Inspector as "Player" and the OverlapSphere doesnt collide with the player object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETLhq.png). Is there something I don't know? I researched a lot and couldn't find anything